# Node.js Node-API. Error in .cpp Native C++ Module ruines javascript app. How to catch error properly

Tags: c++, node.js, api, node-gyp

The server is written on Node.js. I need to use the Native C++ Module, so I decided to use Node-API.
It usually works fine but sometimes the app downs and I want to know what happens. I'm trying to find the correct way to try-catch any error.
**My gyp file:**

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "cca",
      "sources": [
        "./src/filter.cpp",
        "./src/cca.cpp",
        "./src/index.cpp"
      ],
      "include_dirs": [
        "<!@(node -p \"require('node-addon-api').include\")"
      ],
      'defines': [ 'NAPI_CPP_EXCEPTIONS' ],
    }
  ]
}
```

**My Napi file (index.cpp):**

```
Napi::Value filterWrapped( const Napi::CallbackInfo& info) 
{
    Napi::Env env = info.Env();
    try {
        if (info.Length() < 1)
        {
            Napi::TypeError::New(env, "Wrong number of arguments").ThrowAsJavaScriptException();
            return env.Null();
        }
        ........some code here
     } catch (...) {
        Napi::Error::New(env, "A native exception was thrown").ThrowAsJavaScriptException();
    }
}
```

**My Node.js code**

```
const ccaModule = require('./build/Release/cca.node');
try{
    dataArray = ccaModule.filterWrapped(arg);
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

But this doesn't help.
I would be very grateful if someone can give me a tip on how I can catch all errors that happens.

Answer (score 0):

You have to return a value from your function, add this statement after your second exception:

```
return env.Null();
```

But since you have NAPI_CPP_EXCEPTIONS defined, you can just throw the errors, no need to call ThrowAsJavaScriptException(), so this would also work:

```
throw Napi::Error::New(env, "A native exception was thrown");
```

You can find more details [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-api/blob/main/doc/error_handling.md#exceptions).

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me. My javascript application crashes. But I want to catch errors and work with them properly.